# Get list of tasks started by a user on a Linux system

Tags: linux, tasks

I need to get running tasks which are started by a user. I tried several commands such as

```
xlsclients
```

This commands does almost what I need but it is lack of user information. It lists all tasks (actually windows) at once without user name.

```
ps aux -u *username*
```

This gives processes by user but it includes all system tasks too, like:

```
/sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
/usr/sbin/gpm -m /dev/input/mice -t exps2
```

etc.

So I want to list tasks run by a user but excluding system-related ones.

Comment: How do you define "system-related tasks"?

Comment: Tasks were not started by the user. For example; if the user logs in and starts a browser, I just want to see google-chrome.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "system-related tasks" - GUI programs, backgrounded commands, orphan commands, or something else?

Comment: All you mentioned are what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

If you want non-[orphan](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#PIDs_and_parents) processes:

- `pgrep -u "$USER"` prints the PIDs started by the current user
- `pgrep -u "$USER" -P 1` prints the orphan PIDs started by the current user

Combining these you can get the non-orphan PIDs started by the current user:

```
pgrep -u "$USER" | grep -Fvx "$(pgrep -u "$USER" -P 1)"
```

You can pass the resulting list into `ps`, `top` or other programs to get the details on each process.